# 3DES CBC Encryption in PHP with a 16 byte key

Tags: php, encryption, 3des, cbc-mode

I've been trying to make a 3DES algorithm in PHP. I made it in Java and it works well, but the PHP version gives me a different result; here is my code:

```
function String2Hex($string){
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}

function hexToAscii($inputHex) {
    $inputHex = str_replace(' ', '', $inputHex);
    $inputHex = str_replace('\x', '', $inputHex);
    $ascii = pack('H*', $inputHex);
    return $ascii;
}

$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

$iv =  '0000000000000000';

$key = '75ABFD405D018A9BD0E66D23DA3B6DC8';
printf("KEY: %s\n", String2Hex($key));

$cleartext = '0436A6BFFFFFFFA8';
printf("<br>TEXT: %s\n\n", $cleartext);

if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, hexToAscii($key), $iv) != -1)
{
    $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher, hexToAscii($cleartext));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

    printf("<br><br>3DES encrypted:\n%s\n\n", strtoupper(bin2hex($cipherText)));
}
```

**It must give me: 76FB62FB3AFD6677

But it gives me: E01BD1085F0126A2**

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you want 3DES? [3DES, which has a 64-bit block cipher, is a bad idea in 2015](https://gist.github.com/tqbf/be58d2d39690c3b366ad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple DES is defined for key sizes of 192 bit (168 bit without parity). This assumes three independent subkeys. Since you only have one 128 bit, you need to stretch the two keys into three subkeys. Since 3DES is usually executed as a Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt (EDE) scheme, the first and the last subkey can be the same.

If your current key is `K1 || K2`, then you can try `K1 || K2 || K1` or `K2 || K1 || K2` as the final key. I've tried it for you and the first suggestion works.

Also, you forgot to decode the IV from Hex. Here is the full code:

```
function String2Hex($string){
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
return $hex;
}

function hexToAscii($inputHex) {
    $inputHex = str_replace(' ', '', $inputHex);
    $inputHex = str_replace('\x', '', $inputHex);
    $ascii = pack('H*', $inputHex);
    return $ascii;
}

$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

$iv =  '0000000000000000';

//$key = '75ABFD405D018A9BD0E66D23DA3B6DC8';
$key = '75ABFD405D018A9BD0E66D23DA3B6DC875ABFD405D018A9B';
printf("KEY: %s\n", $key);

$cleartext = '0436A6BFFFFFFFA8';
printf("<br>TEXT: %s\n\n", $cleartext);

if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, hexToAscii($key), hexToAscii($iv)) != -1)
{
    $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher, hexToAscii($cleartext));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

    printf("<br>3DES encrypted:\n%s\n\n", strtoupper(bin2hex($cipherText)));
}
```

Output:

```
KEY: 75ABFD405D018A9BD0E66D23DA3B6DC875ABFD405D018A9B
TEXT: 0436A6BFFFFFFFA8
3DES encrypted: 76FB62FB3AFD6677
```